# How many equivalence classes does this equivalence relation have?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let Σ={0,1}, ≡L is an equivalence relation for set L Let s = 10100 and L = {s} be the language containing only string s

L−x = {y:xy∈L}

x ≡L y ⟺ L−x = L−y

I can count 6:

L-empty

L-1

L-10

L-101

L-1010

L-10100

However I believe the there should be 7 states here. Can anyone point out what I'm missing please?
What would "the partition of Σ∗ in the equivalence classes of ≡L." be then?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What about all the other strings such as $0$, $00$, $01$, $11$ etc. for which $L-x=\{\}$ ?

Comment: An equivalence relation for a set L can only partition L and no others sets.  As L is a singleton set, there is exactly one equivalence class, namely L.